# How do I increase my root volume

Tags: ssh, partition, raid, volume

I have a server using software RAID (raid1) and I need to increase my volume on my root partition. I've been googling around with no luck of finding out how I can do this. I have 2x1TB RAID1.

My df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   20G     0 100% /
/dev/root        20G   20G     0 100% /,
devtmpfs        3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            788M  256K  788M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  4.0K 1020K   1% /tmp
/dev/md3        898G   72M  852G   1% /home
```

My fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e1568

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   fd  Linux RAID autodetect
/dev/sdb2        40962048    42008575      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3        42008576  1953517567   955754496   fd  Linux RAID autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a0d60

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   fd  Linux RAID autodetect
/dev/sda2        40962048    42008575      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        42008576  1953517567   955754496   fd  Linux RAID autodetect

Disk /dev/md3: 978.7 GB, 978692538368 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 238938608 cylinders, total 1911508864 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5119728 cylinders, total 40957824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Are you also using LVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite tricky to do on a live system. The organization you've chosen is very inflexible to resizing.

My recommendation is to move some large chunk of the root partition into `/home` and create a symbolic link.

---

If you really want to resize, here's a way to do it. I recommend practicing first in a virtual machine, because you risk making your system unbootable (if you're lucky) or losing your data (if you're unlucky). Do make sure your backups are up to date.

1. Stop all services other than sshd. We're going to desynchronize the RAID, and any modification to files on `/` or `/home` performed after this point will be lost.
2. Manually fail the RAID components on `/dev/sdb` and remove them from the array. Also turn off swap from `/dev/sdb2`.

   ```
   mdadm /dev/md1 -f /dev/sdb1
   mdadm /dev/md1 -r /dev/sdb1
   mdadm /dev/md3 -f /dev/sdb3
   mdadm /dev/md3 -r /dev/sdb3
   swapoff /dev/sdb2
   ```
3. Repartition `/dev/sdb`. I recommend that you use a more flexible partitioning scheme, with LVM. That way any resizing you want to do later will be a lot easier. Make a single RAID 1 volume spanning the whole disk, except for the swap space. I'll assume the new volume for RAID is `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` is again swap space. It doesn't matter in what order the volumes are.
4. Make `/dev/sdb1` part of a RAID 1 volume with a single component for now.

   ```
   mdadm --create /dev/md4 -l 1 -n 2 missing /dev/sdb2
   ```
5. Make the new RAID volume an [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) physical volume, and create a volume group containing it.

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/md4
   vgcreate main /dev/md4
   ```
6. Create a root logical volume with the desired size, and a home LV spanning the rest of the available space.

   ```
   lvcreate --size 40g -n root main
   lvcreate --size 100%FREE -n home main
   ```
7. Create filesystems on `/dev/mapper/main_root` and `/dev/mapper/main_home`. Also run `mkswap /dev/sdb2`.
8. Mount the new filesystems and copy your data there.

   ```
   mkdir /media/new_root /media/new_home
   mount /dev/mapper/main_root /media/new_root
   mount /dev/mapper/main_home /media/new_home
   cp -ax / /media/new_root
   cp -ax / /media/new_home
   ```
9. Run `chroot /media/new_root` and update the storage configuration to the new organization. You'll need to update `/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/mapper/main_root` on `/home`. Also comment out the swap entry for `/dev/sda2`. You'll also need to make the new system bootable, which depends on your bootloader. Note that LILO and Grub2 can boot from LVM but Grub 0.9x cannot.
10. Reboot to the new system. Only do this after you've done all these steps in a VM and confirmed that it works!
11. Repartition `/dev/sda` identically to `/dev/sdb`.
12. Run `mkswap /dev/sda2` then `swapon /dev/sda2`. You can now uncomment the entry for `/dev/sda2` in `/etc/fstab`.
13. Add `/dev/sda1` to the new RAID1 array and let it synchronize in the background.

    ```
    mdadm --add /dev/md4 /dev/sda1
    ```